# Creating Domino session in liferay

Tags: liferay, lotus-domino

I have a requirement like while login in liferay i have to initiate a domino session for that user. How about the possibilities and is there any work around.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Domino needs to be configured for SSO.
Liferay and Domino servers must share the same DNS Domain.
You need to create the LtpaToken cookie manually.
I achieved this by writing a custom com.liferay.portal.security.auth.Authenticator that intercepts the username and password (after the Liferay login) and tries to login on Domino via DIIOP.

lotus.domino.Session session = lotus.domino.NotesFactory.create(hostname, username, password);
If the login succeeds you can get the LtpaToken by calling session.getSessionToken();
Just put the token into a custom Cookie called LtpaToken by default which is valid for the DNS Domain your servers share.